# Can degenerations have derived equivalent fibres

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Let $\pi: X \rightarrow B$ be a proper flat morphism of varieties and $0 \in B$ be a closed point such that on $B \setminus 0$ the morphism $\pi$ is trivial, isomorphic to $(B \setminus 0) \times F$. Do there exist examples where the fibre $X_0$ is derived equivalent to $F$ but not isomorphic? What if I ask that the derived equivalence be induced by $\pi$?

Comment: I believe this already happens for the family $F\times (B\setminus\{0\}) = (\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1)\times (B\setminus\{0\})$ specializing to a Hirzebruch surface $\Sigma_2$, i.e., the blowing up of the vertex of a singular quadric cone in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: @JasonStarr I am afraid this cannot happen because $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is Fano, so by Bondal-Orlov a variety derived equivalent to it would also have to be isomorphic.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I was thinking the same. I have to say that the situation I am thinking about is a little more general, I just want to work with the derived categories, not the varieties. I don't know how this affects the question!

Comment: @PiotrAchinger.  You are correct!  The two schemes are deformation equivalent, and they have isomorphic Chow groups and K-groups, but they are not derived equivalent.

Comment: @JasonStarr I think there may be a misunderstanding then, I want an example where the central fibre is derived equivalent to a general fibre (but not isomorphic).

Comment: @LawrenceJackBarrott.  I understand.  The example I gave in the previous comment was wrong.  I am writing an answer below (in progress).

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! I feel that at this point I owe you a beer for your answers.

Comment: @LawrenceJackBarrott: Do you assume $F$ to be smooth?

Comment: @Sasha Let's say yes, as a side question am I right in thinking that smoothness is an intrinsic property of a derived category (so that Perf equals Db)?

Comment: My new example also does fails :(  In addition to $X\to B$ in my previous comment, consider a stacky version $\mathcal{X}\to B$ that equals the same product family over $B\setminus\{0\}$, yet whose central fiber is a smooth Deligne-Mumford stack with coarse moduli space equal to a singular quadric cone (I think I can write such $\mathcal{X}$ explicitly).  The Hilbert scheme of length $n$ closed subschemes of fibers of $X/B$ is symplectic equivalent to the relative Hilbert scheme of $\mathcal{X}/B$.  Namikawa applies, but to the central fibers of $X/B$ and $\mathcal{X}/B$, not generic fibers.

Comment: @LawrenceJackBarrott: Yes, smoothness is an intrinsic property: a proper $X$ is smooth if and only if $D^b(X)$ is $Ext$-finite, i.e., $\dim \oplus_i Ext^i(F,G) < \infty$ for all $F,G \in D^b(X)$.

Comment: @Sasha Wonderful, at all stages my triangulated category will be fixed in what I want, so I can ensure smoothness.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think this is possible. What I write below is not a proof, rather this is the reason why I think so.

Assume $\pi \colon X \to B$ is such a family. Let us consider it as a deformation family of the central fiber $F_0$. Note that $F_0$ is smooth if the general fiber is smooth, since smoothness can be detected by the derived category.

Let $\kappa \in H^1(F_0,T_{F_0})$ be the tangent vector for the deformation. Note that there is a natural morphism
$$
H^1(F_0,T_{F_0}) \to HH^2(D^b(F_0)) \cong \bigoplus_{p+q = 2} H^q(F_0,\Lambda^p T_{F_0})
$$
to the second Hochschild cohomology group, which is the tangent space to deformations of $D^b(F_0)$. This map is injective, so if $\kappa \ne 0$, the deformation of the category in the family is non-trivial as well.

Comment: This seems like a good way to think about it, there is a similar question in Hartshorne's book on deformation theory if I remember.

Comment: Thinking about this I feel I need to ask, is the Hochschild cohomology defined without the tensor product structure? Otherwise how are we comparing deformations of the central fibre to the general fibre?

Comment: @LawrenceJackBarrott: Yes, the definition of Hochschild cohomology does not require tensor structure. Morally, it is equal to $Ext$-groups from the identity functor to itself; to define it rigorously one only needs an enhancement (for instance a DG-enhancement) for the category.

Comment: I was playing about with it earlier today and indeed found of course you don't need the tensor structure. How strange, that answers so many of my questions!